# How to initialize MapView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, maps, mapkit

Goal:

1. I have a class that declares a map view and finds the user's current location. This class is called `MapController()`.
2. I have another class that needs to call `MapController()`, and drop a pin at the user's current location.

Problem:

While I'm in the other class and trying to call `MapController()`, `MapController()`'s MapView never gets initialized.

Solution I need:

How do I initialize a MapView?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. This is too abstract (and convoluted) to follow. Generally you just add a `MKMapView` to your scene in IB or programmatically instantiate a `MKMapView` and then add it to the view hierarchy (and set the constraints so it's laid out correctly).

Comment: I can try to describe it but I have previously and progressed to no avail. If you could it would be easier if you just looked at my project. It's pretty straight forward. Here is the Dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymeoimza0oc2r2a/notes.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

A number of times you are referencing:

```
let map = MapController().mapView
```

That isn't doing what you think it does:

- Rather than referencing a map on an existing view controller, `MapController()` is instantiating a brand new view controller. But since you don't do anything with that view controller, but rather just let it fall out of scope, it is immediately deallocated.
- Even if you didn't let it fall out of scope (e.g. you transitioned to it somehow), you're not instantiating that through the storyboard, so the outlets will be `nil`. If you were really trying to instantiate a new instance of `MapController`, you'd do something like:

  ```
  let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapControllerScene")
  ```
- Frankly, even if you solved the above issues, one view controller has no business interacting directly with the `MKMapView` of another view controller scene.

So, the question is what is the correct way to achieve what you intended.

There are three basic techniques:

1. Keep the "add note" and the map view loosely coupled and have Note Detail View Controller simply post a notification to `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()` and then have the map view observe that custom notification.
2. Navigate through the view controller hierarchy to get to the map view controller (e.g. the second child of the navigation bar's tab controller). Or actively pass the map view controller reference as a parameter that you pass from view controller to view controller. Anyway, if you had a reference to the existing map view controller, you can now pass data back directly. You might want to implement a protocol to avoid tight coupling of these two classes.
3. Perform some unwind segue to navigate back from note detail view controller back to the map view and then use `prepareForSegue` to pass the data back. In iOS 9 you no longer have to unwind solely to a class higher in the view controller hierarchy, though that makes life a little easier for you if you do that.

Comment: wow, thanks so much! just a question about the 2nd technique though. How would I go about programmatically passing the map view controller reference as a parameter? This seems like something I should be able to use for other projects as well…

Comment: Well, if the map view controller  is presenting the view controller that needs the reference, it's as simple as passing it in `prepareForSegue`. If it's another tab in a `UITabBarController`, then you have to navigate up to the tab bar controller (e.g. `if let mapController = self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? MapViewController { ... }` or something like that).